# How to take screen shot of video size by ffmpeg

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I want to take screen shot of size of the video. How can if take it , 
as now i can take the screen shot of this size like 120x90 by following code.

```
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss $second -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -s 120x90 -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $image 2>&1";
```

Please suggest .

Thanks

Comment: @leppie Really? What is it then?

Comment: @zmol: Command line invocation of an application...

Comment: @leppie Not really. You'll notice his command is stored in a string php variable `$cmd = ""` and he will use `shell_exec($cmd);` after that because that's how ffmpeg is used from within php. So no, he's not on the command line. This is just how ffmpeg is used.

Comment: @zmol: tagged as php in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer because I haven't use the ffmpeg library in a while, but the general idea is

- use ffmpeg to get the dimensions of the video before calling the command
- string substitute the correct values instead of 120x90
- call the command